# How do I make a video in portrait mode fit in a square cell?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Consider a UICollectionView where each cell contains a UIView. The UIView in the cell will be linked to an AVPlayerLayer that will play a video. However, videos taken in portrait mode do not seem to scale properly. When I use the `videoGravity` property of `AVPlayerLayer` and set it to `resizeAspectFill` so video will fill the cell, it seems to cut the video.

> Is there a way to make the video taken in portrait fit a square cell?

The set-up is as follows:

A cell in the UICollectionView feed will contain a UIView, which will hold the video player. This is the UIView's class **PlayerViewClass**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {

        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The cell **MyCollectionViewCell** has an IBOutlet linked to this UIView:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: PlayerViewClass!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib() 

   //Setup, not relevant

   }

}
```

The Feed's collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath delegate method in the **FeedViewController** is as follows:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

      if let cell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell {

      ...

      //Configuring the cell

      ...

      //Video player
      let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: post.fullURL)

      **//TODO: Configure layout so the portrait video scales appropriately**

      //Setting cell's player
      cell.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer

      //Play
      cell.playerView.player?.play()

    }
    return cell
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I can't seem to find an answer thus far!

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Sure! I've just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems to cut the video

Yes, that's what `resizeAspectFill` does. It fills the square and whatever doesn't fit falls outside the square and is cut off. No surprise there. If that's not what you wanted, why did you ask for `resizeAspectFill`?

Perhaps you meant `resizeAspect`. That will display the whole video, inside the given limits (the square).

Comment: Thanks so much! I eventually realized I had a few conflicting NSLayoutConstraints for some reason.